# Passing range to sparklines in Excel

Tags: excel, parameters, sparklines

I used

```
CONCATENATE("N";MATCH(M4;M12:M401;0)+10;":";"N";MATCH(M4;M12:M401;1)+10)
```

to produce this result in cell `I4`

```
 N67:N231
```

I have tryed to pass this range to sparkline using `CELL REFERENCE`, `INDIRECT`(`CELL REFERENCE and NAME VARIABLE`. Nothing worked. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get this to work I had to create a Name ranged that used indirect on the cell containing my calculated range string. Passing the name ranged to the Sparklines Data Range then works.

[image: Named Range]
[image: SparkLine Range]

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly what I wanted. Works like a charm.

Comment: You're welcome. Would you kindly mark this as the answer? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could also use vba and alter the `.SourceData` property of the sparkline(s) - assign your new values direct through vba.

```
Public Sub test
    For Each myRange In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A3")  '<=Change to range containing sparklines
        myRange.SparklineGroups.Item(1).SourceData = Activesheet.Cells(myRange.Row, "B")  '<==assumes new values to use in column B of same row as sparkline to update
    Next   
End Sub
```